# do i need my data files when i turn .py into .exe with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, excel, exe, pyinstaller

### (first time).
so im trying to use 2 excel files in my code, one for grabbing dataset and another for storing data, and I tried to make an exe file with pyinstaller but i think i should put those 2 files somewhere or do something with them but due to being very new to coding, I really have 0 clue.

used --add-data dataset.xlsx;. and got this error[screenshot][1]:
Start? y/n
y
traceback (most recent call last):
file "neo.py, line 4, in 
file "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
[1808] Failed to execute script neo
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8wsn.png

I think there is a problem with this line:

```
    start = input("Start? y/n \n")                                              
    while True:
     if start in ["y", "yes", "Yes", "YES", "Y"]:
      print("Starting")
      break
    elif start in ["n", "no", "NO", "No", "N"]:
     print("Have a nice day!")
     exit()
     break
    else:
     print("Invalid answer, try again")
     exit()
     break
```

(sorry for being sloppy, again, im very new :D)

Comment: Did you create those Excel files before running your program? Or files are creating during program execution?

Comment: @Alderven I think one of them is already existing and the other is created during user input

Comment: @Alderven I could also try and fit both of them into single excel if that solves my problem

Comment: Anyway you have to store this single excel somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used --add-data file.xlsx as my friend here suggested and than I checked and as i had python added to path but it wasnt activated so i went and activated it with

```
     c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base
```

in cmd, than used pyinstaller.
ofc it wasnt in this directory but u get the gest

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,**

You need one of those files according to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573987/do-i-need-my-data-files-when-i-turn-py-into-exe-with-pyinstaller#comment112419545_63573987). You can add it to exe with `--add-data "file1.xlsx"` option. See [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose those files directly when you run the exe. I use this for importing Excel data from whatever location:

```
import pandas as pd
import easygui

def ExcelData():
    data = pd.ExcelFile(easygui.fileopenbox("Please select the Excel file with data to be uploaded:", "Data"))
    sheetlist = data.sheet_names
    sheet = easygui.choicebox("Select a Sheet to be Extracted:" , "Data", sheetlist)
    output = data.parse(sheet_name=sheet)
    return(output)
```